# How to detect when a new unique term has been inserted into an index on a specific field in a specific index in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, cron, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0

I currently have a cron job that is looking at a field called "ex.set" and performs these tasks:

1. For every index, run a terms aggregation on the field "ex.set"
2. For every index, get every existing alias
3. For every unique term appearing in an index in "ex.set", if it does not have an existing alias, create a filtered alias

The job runs every ten minutes but most of the time does not find anything. Is there a way or a plugin (compatible with 2.3.x), that will automatically detect when a new unique term has been inserted into an index on a specific field in a specific index? And then if there is a unique item trigger the creation of a filtered alias on that index? Thank you in advance for any ideas or solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe you can use [Watcher plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/introduction.html) to do this. It has a default license valid for 30 days, after which [some features are disabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/license-management.html#license-expiration) and afterwards you'd need a valid license to have it fully working again.

The basic idea is that your first two steps can be put in a [chain input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/2.3/input.html#input-chain) as [search inputs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/2.3/input.html#input-search) which will collect the data.

Then, the additional step which compares the existent aliases with the terms from that aggregation can be considered as a [script condition](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/2.3/condition.html#condition-script) where you do your magic of comparing the two sets. If your condition establishes that a new alias needs to be created then, in the `action` part of the watch you can use a [webhook action](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/2.3/actions.html#actions-webhook) to call the create alias REST command on the index.